# Sum column values of two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called 'a' which contains the geographic weights of funds with isin code in column 'isin' (index column):

```
              U.S.  Canada  U.K.
isin
LU1739554647  0.08   0.210  0.11
LU0599946893  0.14   0.026  0.07
LU1460782227  0.25   0.050  0.14
```

Then I have another dataframe called 'b' with other instrument (that are not funds) and contains only one column with country code ('country') and the weight ('weight). asset_ID is the isin code of the instrument:

```
       asset_ID country  weight
0  US1912161007    U.S.   0.005
1  GB0007188757     U.K.   0.100
```

My goal is to calculate the geographical allocation of the entire portfolio by aggregating and summing up the weights of countries in the two dataframes.
To do this, first I sum the column values for every column in dataframe 'a' with this line of code `a.sum(axis = 0, skipna = True)` and this output:

```
U.S.      0.470
Canada    0.286
U.K.      0.320
```

At this point I don't know how to aggregate and sum the values of the above output with dataframe 'b'. The desidered output result is like this:

```
U.S.      0.475
Canada    0.286
U.K.      0.420
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? I specify that the dataframe 'a' can have a variable number of columns as many as there are countries and the isin codes are always unique as well as the country codes.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with multiple values by [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and then `sum`:

```
s = df1.mul(df2.pivot('asset_ID','country','weight'), fill_value=1).sum()
print (s)
Canada    0.286
U.K.      0.420
U.S.      0.475
dtype: float64
```